# read xls with c# only getting part of data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im using c# to read data from an xls spreadsheet. it reads if fine but for some reason its missing the end off the content on some of the long data cells.

below is some of my code

```
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=W:\translations-mk2.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
{
    //List columns you need from the Excel file
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [phrases$]", connection);



    connection.Open();


    // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            int x = 1;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //Response.Write(dr[1].ToString() + " : " + dr[6].ToString() + "<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>");
                string dbId = dr[0].ToString();
                string htmlControl = dr[1].ToString();
                string eng = dr[2].ToString();
                string german = dr[4].ToString();
                string greek = dr[6].ToString();
                if (dbId == "65")
                {
                    Response.Write("greek: " + dr[6].ToString());
                }
```

the content is in greek so what should be in the string is

Καλωσορίσατε στον ιστότοπο της ADHD Alliance for Change (Συμμαχία για Αλλαγή στη ΔΕΠΥ). Η εκστρατεία ADHD Alliance for Change (Συμμαχία για Αλλαγή στη ΔΕΠΥ) είναι ένα ευρωπαϊκό έργο που τελεί υπό την καθοδήγηση μιας Συντονιστικής Επιτροπής Ανεξάρτητων Ευρωπαίων Εμπειρογνωμόνων σε θέματα ΔΕΠΥ (Διαταραχή Ελλειμματικής Προσοχής και Υπερκινητικότητας), το οποίο υλοποιείται με την υποστήριξη ομάδων υπεράσπισης ασθενών και αναπτύσσεται και χρηματοδοτείται από τη φαρμακευτική εταιρεία Shire.

but what is in the string is this

Καλωσορίσατε στον ιστότοπο της ADHD Alliance for Change (Συμμαχία για Αλλαγή στη ΔΕΠΥ). Η εκστρατεία ADHD Alliance for Change (Συμμαχία για Αλλαγή στη ΔΕΠΥ) είναι ένα ευρωπαϊκό έργο που τελεί υπό την καθοδήγηση μιας Συντονιστικής Επιτροπής Ανεξάρτητων Ευρ

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: how can i stop it chopping the end of the content off

Comment: Can you add an example into the question: what it should be vs what it looks like after your code has read it

Comment: Are you in a position to get the file as an xlsx and read the file using OpenXML API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the value of TypeGuessRows in the Registry. This value specifies the number or rows scanned when determining the data types for each column. The default is eight and it's likely that none of the first eight rows contain more than 255 characters. You can change the value to a number greater than eight or specify a value of zero, which will cause all rows to be scanned. Keep in mind that using a value of zero may incur a performance hit.

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows

Comment: that sounds about right, however, I can't find the registry entry your referring to?

Comment: Have your tried with "Search" in Regedit? For win7 64b, you can find it in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel, read http://houckma.blogspot.be/2012/02/connecting-to-excel-files-on-64-bit.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the excel data reader ?
http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

Comment: because its wrote in c# would that not do the same?